# Editing a custom object record in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I achieve editing a custom object record by listing all the records and selecting a particular record in checkbox which will open popup window for editing purpose in visualforce ?

Comment: Adding some more detail will help to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried already, do you have any code sample you're stuck with?
Be careful what you wish for, "all records" when it's tens of thousands of them will likely blow the page's viewstate. I mean solution might be as simple as making a page with [`<apex:enhancedList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) in it...

Read up about [StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm).

It's old feature, it's battle-tested, there will be tons of examples how to use it like https://developer.secure.force.com/cookbook/recipe/editing-multiple-records-using-a-visualforce-list-controller or http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/pagination-using-standard-set-controller-salesforce/

Looks like you need something very simple that just displays list of links & these links will have JavaScript (`window.open` function?) that creates a popup with record id passed.